# Clear button for input field in ionic2

Tags: ionic2, input-field

What is the easy way to add a clear (x) button to an input field in ionic 2? It's supposed to delete the entered content.
[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Clear Icon</ion-label>
  <ion-input placeholder="Clear Input" clearInput></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

Just add a `clearinput` attribute to your inputs and it'll show an `x` button in the right side of input.

There's also a `clearOnEdit` attribute which clears the input when the user focuses on it again.

Hope this helps

Comment: Nice! I was not aware of this. +1

Comment: Works perfect as of **Feb 2020**, using **Ionic 5**. Thanks a ton for sharing!